# Reverse for 'detail.view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

My urls.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns= [
url(r'^$', views.detail, name= 'detail' ),
url(r'^testapp/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.image_detail, name='image_detail'),
]
```

views.py looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Album

def detail(request):
    all_album = Album.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'testapp/detail.html', {'all_album' : all_album })


def image_detail(request, pk):
album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'testapp/image_detail.html', {'album' : album })
```

detail.html template is this:

```
{% include "navbar.html" %}
<div class="container">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {% for album in all_album %}
        <a href="{% url 'testapp:image_detail' pk=album.pk %}">  <img src="{{ album.image.url }}" height="420"></a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.10.7
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/sanjana/sample/testapp/templates/testapp/detail.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'detail.view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   1 : {% include "navbar.html" %}
   2 :  <div class="container">    
   3 :   <div class="row">
   4 :     <div class="col-sm-4">
   5 :         {% for album in all_album %}
   6 :              <a href="{% url 'testapp:image_detail' pk=album.pk %}">  <img src="{{ album.image.url }}" height="420"></a>
   7 :         {% endfor %}
   8 :     </div>
   9 :       </div>
   10 : </div>
```

This is the main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('testapp.urls', namespace= "testapp")),
]
```

This is navbar.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class=" a navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'testapp:detail.view' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

I can't spot the cause of the error hence I'm unable to progress with my study. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the main urls.py as well.

Comment: can you post the navbar.html code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'testapp:detail.view' %}">
```

change this line in navbar

to

```
<a href="{% url 'testapp:detail' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your template like this,

```
{% for album in all_album %}
    <a href="{% url 'testapp:image_detail' pk=album.pk %}">  <img src="{{ album.image.url }}" height="420"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Change **image** to **album** in your template, like this **{% for album in all_album %}**

And change the line in navbar,

```
<a href="{% url 'testapp:detail' %}">
```

Comment: My model name is Album. so album.pk must be correct, right? However I tried it and the same error showed up. @Fazil Zaid

Comment: but in your template, you are referring to the album object as image

Comment: hope you get what I mean..!!

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned. But the error still remains.

Comment: Could you please double check that the variables are the same in the for loop? like in my answer?

Comment: Yes.Both the variables are having the same name.I have also added the traceback along with the question.

Comment: I have added the main urls.py

Comment: could you add the navbar also?

Comment: added navbar.html also